# Apache Rewrite rule not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, apache2, elastic-beanstalk

I am using an AWS Elastic Load Balancer, and have set up the [following rule](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/) to convert `http` traffic to `https`.

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd_redirect.conf`

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
    </VirtualHost>
```

However, when I access my website via its domain ([www.thewhozoo.com](http://www.thewhozoo.com)), I can see the protocol is `http` and not `https`.

Any ideas why the rewrite rule is not working?

Thanks

**More info**

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
...
Include conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf
...
```

The above is created on deployment by:

`.ebextensions/myapp.config`

```
container_commands:
      01_setup_apache:
          command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd_redirect.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        <VirtualHost *:80>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
        </VirtualHost>
```

ELB Listeners

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a configuration snippet `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf`

Typically such snippets get loaded by an [`Include`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) or [`IncludeOptional`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#includeoptional)  directive

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

or

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

from your main `httpd.conf`.

The problem is that those snippets only apply to your main configuration and don't apply to any `VirtualHost` sections...

Either include those settings in the virtual host definition, or load that snippet there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.thewhozoo.com
   Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Or even better, [don't use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) and set:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.thewhozoo.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.thewhozoo.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. If I use `Redirect "/" "https://www.thewhozoo.com/"`, where do I put it? i.e. in which config file?

Comment: In the config file where you define the virtual host for your domain. That might be in a `sites-available/` or in  your `conf.d/` - I don't know.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but do I add it to a `.config` file in `.ebextensions`, so that at deploy time it is added to a `.conf` file? e.g. in my example above, add it to the `.ebextensions/myapp.config` file?

Comment: I'm similarly ignorant, I know Apache httpd, but I don't know what .ebextensions does... :(

Comment: `.ebextensions` is a directory you add to your app root at build time, and when you deploy Tomcat, the commands are executed before the server starts.

Comment: I added a `virtual_hosts.conf` file with the following, but no success. `$ cat virtual_hosts.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.thewhozoo.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.thewhozoo.com/"
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: I added a `virtual_hosts.conf` file with the following, but no success. `$ cat virtual_hosts.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.thewhozoo.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.thewhozoo.com/"
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: The `httpd.con` already has a `Include conf.d/*.conf` in it, so I think the original `ssl_rewrite.conf` is being included, but not sure why it's not working.