# Apacher Tomcat debug conf files

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, apache2, elastic-beanstalk

I am using Tomcat 8 on AWS an Elastic Load Balancer. I am trying to do a rewrite, but nothing is happening, see [here for details](https://serverfault.com/questions/857962/apache-rewrite-rule-not-working).

I have:

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
...
Include conf.d/*.conf
Include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf
...
```

The `httpd.conf` is set up by AWS, and I have not modified it. However, I would like to debug if the `Included` conf file are actually being executed.

**Question**

How do you put a line in a conf file to write debug info to the logs (so that I can determine which commands are being executed)? Once done, which logs will they write to?

Thanks

**Question**

Comment: [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html) can be used to display your active config, for debugging mod_rewrite issues:   use mod_rewrite's [logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) options

Comment: Hi HBruijn, thanks for the info.  I add the following to my `httpd.conf`, but when I go to `example.com/site-info`, I get a `404`. does that mean the `httpd.conf` is not being executed? `<Location "/server-info">
    SetHandler server-info
    Require host example.com
</Location>`